# Media Queries not working, possible syntax issue

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm trying out media queries for the first time but I cannot find where I went wrong. I have the code down below, and I'm assuming it's a syntax error. When I try to run it, nothing happens! Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="styles/mobile.css" />
```

styles/mobile.css

```
.color {
        height:100%;
    }

.anim {
        height:0%
    }

.scrollup {
        display:none;
    }

.scrolldown {
        display:none;
    }

 .menu-icon {
        display:none;
    }
```

Comment: you are using device width are you sure is that what you want?

Comment: and I guess those styles are in styles/mobile.css right? if not unknowndomain wrote you the answer

Comment: The way you've posted the question is confusing.  Is that a direct copy/paste from your HTML, or are the styles actually in `styles/mobile.css`?  If they're in the HTML document like that it certainly won't work.

Comment: @SantiagoRebella woops nice catch :) but Even after changing it it still doesn't work

Comment: @JimGarrison they are in a seperate css file

Answer (score 1):

Typically the media query goes around the CSS in the CSS file, not inline in the `<link>` tag...

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {

    .color {
        height:100%;
    }

    .anim {
        height: 0%;
    }

    .scrollup {
        display: none;
    }

    .scrolldown {
        display: none;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @unknowndomain says, the media query goes inside the CSS file, and also you should have the Viewport meta tag inside your document's head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;">
```

If you don't put that tag the media queries are not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 2 forms of a media query.

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css"/>
```

and

```
<!-- CSS media query within a style sheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
</style>
```

Also, I noticed you are using "Only" and "And" together in your media query. Here is some information on those 2 things:

"**And**"
The and keyword is used for combining multiple media features together, as well as combining media features with media types. A basic media query, a single media feature with the implied all media type, could look like this:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

"**Only**"
The only keyword prevents older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the given styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (color)" href="example.css" />
```

Media queries are case insensitive.  Media queries involving unknown media types are always false.

Comment: I should also point out that it's not best practice to use Display:none. http://laurakalbag.com/display-none/

Comment: also this article: http://css-tricks.com/places-its-tempting-to-use-display-none-but-dont/